# Can anyone explain the sliding windows are used in LSTMs?

Tags: keras, lstm, sliding-window

As far as I know, the LSTM has a loop that inputs from the last hidden layer resulting the model to have a long short term memory. Then why use sliding windows?

Can you also explain how sliding window works in 'programming with keras' perspective?(or leave a link that explains the working) For example:

```
slide_window = 10
train1, train2 = slwindow_df(train, slide_window)
test1, test2 = slwindow_df(test, slide_window)

model.compile(loss ='mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'adam')
model.fit(train1, train2, epochs =60, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

Also, I guess this is a really dumb question but is it ok to use different sliding windows while creating a model? (With different lengths)